# SQL 'simple' query syntax error - help!

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, insert

My query returns a syntax error:

Invalid object name 'table.clientinfo'.

Here is my query:

```
INSERT table.clientinfo (name, addr, entry, affiliate ) 
SELECT name, addr, entry, affiliate FROM table.clientinfo WHERE product = 5
```

Is the error due to the insert function not finding 'clientinfo' as it does not exist.

Can anybody give me the correct syntax to create the table first before populating it from the select function?

Answer (score 1):

You want [CREATE TABLE](http://sql-info.de/mysql/examples/CREATE-TABLE-examples.html)

```
CREATE TABLE clientinfo (
         name VARCHAR(100)
         addr VARCHAR(100)
         entry VARCHAR(100)
         affiliate VARCHAR(100)
       );
```

with specific types/sizes for your app. You might want to indicate foriegn and primary keys, constraints etc too

Comment: Can i put this before the rest of my query then? Sorry I am newbie, using my new book also :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
INSERT INTO [tablename] (field1, field2, ... , fieldx)
SELECT ...
```

Or if you want to create the other data directly:

```
SELECT field1, field2, ... , fieldx
INTO newTable
FROM oldtable
WHERE ....
```

Comment: **INTO** is great and useful, but totally **optional** - that's definitely **not** the problem.....

Comment: The database is being used in SQL Server 2005. So if there is no database, shouldn't I create it first? This is what I thought I was after. Also, are the square brackets necessary for it work in SQL server?

Comment: @Joseph - You must have a database as you are selecting from a table in it?

Comment: Srry I mean create a table first.

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, if you want to select and insert into a new table, use this syntax:

```
SELECT name, addr, entry, affiliate 
INTO (new table name)
FROM [table.clientinfo] 
WHERE product = 5
```

You need to `SELECT .... INTO`  and you need to make sure to use proper table names.

If you table name really **has a dot in it** (really really bad practice!), then you **MUST** put that table name in square brackets:  `FROM [table.clientinfo]`

Also, when doing `SELECT .. INTO ...` you cannot select from an existing table and insert into the same existing table - you need to use a new table name for your destination table.